# Add LSTM layer after Conv2D layers and add some other inputs

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, keras-layer

I'm working on a racing game that uses reinforcement learning. To train the model I'm facing an issue when implementing the neural network. I found some examples that use CNN. But it seems like adding extra LSTM layer will increase the model efficiency. I found the following example.

https://team.inria.fr/rits/files/2018/02/ICRA18_EndToEndDriving_CameraReady.pdf

[The network I need to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGuVX.png)

The problem is I'm not sure how can I implement the LSTM layer here. How can I give following inputs to LSTM layer

1. Processed image output
2. current speed
3. last action

Here is the code I'm currently using. I want to add the LSTM layer after Conv2D.

```
    self.__nb_actions = 28
    self.__gamma = 0.99

    #Define the model
    activation = 'relu'
    pic_input = Input(shape=(59,255,3))

    img_stack = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), name='convolution0', padding='same', activation=activation, trainable=train_conv_layers)(pic_input)
    img_stack = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(img_stack)
    img_stack = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=activation, padding='same', name='convolution1', trainable=train_conv_layers)(img_stack)
    img_stack = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(img_stack)
    img_stack = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=activation, padding='same', name='convolution2', trainable=train_conv_layers)(img_stack)
    img_stack = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(img_stack)
    img_stack = Flatten()(img_stack)
    img_stack = Dropout(0.2)(img_stack)

    img_stack = Dense(128, name='rl_dense', kernel_initializer=random_normal(stddev=0.01))(img_stack)

    img_stack=Dropout(0.2)(img_stack)
    output = Dense(self.__nb_actions, name='rl_output', kernel_initializer=random_normal(stddev=0.01))(img_stack)

    opt = Adam()
    self.__action_model = Model(inputs=[pic_input], outputs=output)

    self.__action_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error')
    self.__action_model.summary()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to do that, First, reshape the output of `conv` output and feed it to `lstm` layer. Here is an explained example with various method [Shaping data for LSTM, and feeding output of dense layers to LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138205/shaping-data-for-lstm-and-feeding-output-of-dense-layers-to-lstm/54160952#54160952)