# Stack two LSTM layers in Keras dimension mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to make an LSTM neural net using Keras which gets as input some length of four features and predicts 10 following values. And I can't manage to set proper input dimensions. `X_train` is an array of shape (34,5,4) (repeated observations, the sequence of observations, features) `y_train` is an array of shape(34,10). I can't manage to satisfy the required dimensions.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 4))
model.add(LSTM(30, dropout=0.2, batch_size=window_size))
model.add(LSTM(10, activation=None))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs= epochs,validation_split=0.2,shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Nav, if it solve your problem, please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are stacking two `lstm` layer, you need to use `return_sequence` for first layer, which return output for each time step, which will be feed into 2nd `lstm` layer.

Here is [explained example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138205/shaping-data-for-lstm-and-feeding-output-of-dense-layers-to-lstm/54160952#54160952), by which you can solve your problem.

Comment: I had return_sequence set in the previos version of what i have (it didn't worked for other reasons) but for current version this was the missing puzzle. Thanks