# residual LSTM layers

Tags: keras, lstm, deep-residual-networks

I have trouble understanding tensor behaviour in LSTM layers in keras.

I have preprocessed numeric data that looks like [samples, time steps, featues]. So 10 000 samples, 24 time steps and 10 predictors.

I want to stack residual connections but I am not sure that I am doing it right:

```
x <- layer_input(shape = c(24,10))

x <- layer_lstm(x,units=32,activation="tanh",return_sequences=T)
```

Now shape of x, which is tensor, is [?,?,32]. I was expecting [?,32,10]. Should I reshape the data to be  [samples, features, time steps]? Then I form res:

```
y <- layer_lstm(x,units=32,activation="tanh",return_sequences=T)

res <- layer_add(c(x, y))
```

Now I am not sure if this is correct, or maybe should I go with that instead

```
x <- layer_input(shape = c(24,10))

y <- layer_lstm(x,units=24,activation="tanh",return_sequences=T) # same as time_steps

res <- layer_add(c(x,y)) ## perhaps here data reshaping is neccesary?
```

Any insight is much appreciatied.

JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LSTM` layer will return you dims as `(?,seq_length,out_dims)`, where `out_dims` is `units` in your case. So overall dims will be as

```
x <- layer_input(shape = c(24,10))
# dims of x (?,24,10)
x <- layer_lstm(x,units=32,activation="tanh",return_sequences=T)
# dims of x after lstm_layer (?,24,32)

y <- layer_lstm(x,units=32,activation="tanh",return_sequences=T)
# dims of y (?,24,32)
res <- layer_add(c(x, y))
# dims of res will be (?,24,32), it is addion of output of both lstm_layer.
```

For more info, you can [check-this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138205/shaping-data-for-lstm-and-feeding-output-of-dense-layers-to-lstm/54160952#54160952)

Comment: So LSTM will take all 10 predictors and combine a sequence of 24 in which will be information of all 10 predictors? Did I understood you correctly? @Ankish Bansal

Comment: Yeah, the sequence here can be seen as time steps, so it takes 10 predictors at each time step and compute output of 32 dims and repeat for 24 time steps

Comment: I will just one more sub question. So if I am concerned that I am losing information in deeper layers, which are stacked "y" with another "res", I should save the first "x" in our case and then add it later on? @Ankish Bansal

Comment: I didn't get it, are you saying, what if you add another res block?

Comment: Also, it is loose word to use residual layer, but it is more of stacking two layer. Residual is used, when we actually use residual error as objective for layer output.