# Many-to-many classification with Keras LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am new to RNN's / LSTM's in Keras and need advice on whether / how to use them for my problem, which is many-to-many classification.

I have a number of time series: Approximately 1500 "runs" which each last for about 100-300 time steps and have multiple channels. I understand that I need to zero-pad my data to the maximum number of time steps, so my data looks like this:

```
[nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim]: [1500, 300, 10]
```

Since getting the label for a single time step is impossible without knowing the past even for a human, I could do feature engineering and train a classical classification algorithm, however, I think LSTMs would be a good fit here. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047615/4629950) tells me that for many-to-many classification in Keras, I need to set return_sequences to True. However, I do not quite understand how to proceed from here - do I use the return sequence as input for another, normal layer? How do I connect this to my output layer?

Any help, hints or links to tutorials are greatly appreciated - I found a lot of stuff for many-to-one classification, but nothing good on many-to-many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be many approaches to this, i am specifying which can be good fit to your problem.

If you want to `stack` two `LSTM` layer, then `return-seq` can help to learn for another `LSTM` layer as shown in following example.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, LSTM, Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
from keras import Input, Model

seq_length = 15
input_dims = 10
output_dims = 8 # number of classes
n_hidden = 10
model1_inputs = Input(shape=(seq_length,input_dims,))
model1_outputs = Input(shape=(output_dims,))

net1 = LSTM(n_hidden, return_sequences=True)(model1_inputs)
net1 = LSTM(n_hidden, return_sequences=False)(net1)
net1 = Dense(output_dims, activation='relu')(net1)
model1_outputs = net1

model1 = Model(inputs=model1_inputs, outputs = model1_outputs, name='model1')

## Fit the model
model1.summary()


_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)        (None, 15, 10)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 15, 10)            840       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 10)                840       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 88        
_________________________________________________________________
```

2. Another option is that you can use the complete return sequence as the features for the next layer. In that case make a simple `Dense` layer whose input will be `[batch, seq_len*lstm_output_dims]`.

Note: These features can be useful for classification task, but mostly, we used stacked lstm layer and use its output `with-out complete sequence` as features for the classification layer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138205/shaping-data-for-lstm-and-feeding-output-of-dense-layers-to-lstm/54160952#54160952) answer may be helpful to understand another approaches for `LSTM` architecture for different purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am not sure what you mean with seq_length: Is this supposed to be the number of timesteps, or the batch size? I have 2000 samples, should I not put them into different batches?

Comment: Seq-length represent timesteps in your problem. Can you reframe your 2nd question?

Comment: I think I was able to answer the question myself - it was about batch sizes. I have 2000 samples, but I think I should use mini-batches of 1 to maybe a maximum of 10 samples. If I understand your code correctly (I normally use the other notation), you don't define batch size at all, that's why it says "None" in the Output shape.

Comment: Why is `model1_outputs` defined twice? Does the first definition have a meaning that I don't undersand?